# Find listview items based on criteria from user input

Tags: vb.net

I have list view with many items and I have a column in my list view named Age. I want to use 2 text boxes to search items with certain age. for example, I'll input in `textbox1` value of 20 and in `textbox2` - 30. It should display in list view items with ages 20, 21, 22,.... 30.

Answer (score 0):

you loop through your collection, take item value and evaluate. If it is matches criteria - add it to listview

```
Dim min as integer = Integer.Parse(txtMin.Text)
Dim max as integer = Integer.Parse(txtMax.Text)
For Each person as PersonInfo in myPersonList
    If person.Age >= min AndAlso person.Age <= max Then
        myListview.Items.Add(. . . . . . )
    End If
Next
```

And if you have already items in listview, you can do this trick

```
For Each item as ListViewItem in myListview.Items
    ' here it is depends on where is your column located
    Dim age As Integer = Integer.Parse(item.[SubItems(..)].Text)
    If age >= min AndAlso age <= max Then
        item.BackColor = Color.Yellow ' - highlight items that meet criteria 
    End If
Next
```

Just remember that `Item` has text and can have `Subitems`. Depends where is your column - we don't know this from your post - you will need to use `item.SubItems(i).Text`

And now, I have not tried it but it must work. A dynamic load to your listview

```
Dim itemList As List(Of ListViewItem) ' -- your item database so to speak
' Add your items to it and not to list view
' Then, when button_click happens, use LINQ
myListview.Items.Clear()
itemList.Where(
    Function(item) 
        Dim age As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(item.[SubItems(..)].Text)
        Return (age >= min AndAlso age <= max)
    End Function).ToList().ForEach(Sub(item) myListview.Items.Add(Item))
```

this will populate list with only items that match criteria

Answer (score 0):

if you have two listview, one that diplays the ages and the other is displaying your selected ages within min & max, you can use below code.

```
Dim min As Integer = CInt(txtMin.Text)
Dim max As Integer = CInt(txtMax.Text)
For Each itm In CoursesList.Items
     If CInt(itm) > min And CInt(itm) < max Then
         CoursesList.Items.Add(itm)
     End If
Next
```